# See inherited documentation in PHPStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I usually put the documentation in the interface if I can:

```php
interface SenderInterface
{
    /**
     * Sends Email to user
     *
     * @param UserInterface $receiver
     * @param string $msg
     */
    public function sendEmail(UserInterface $receiver, $msg)
    //...
    {
```

I then inherit the doc like this to avoid redundancy.

```php
class Sender implements SenderInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function sendEmail(UserInterface $receiver, $msg)
    //...
    {
```

Is there a way to see the inherited doc directly into the `Sender class` without having to open the `SenderInterface` in PHPStorm?

Comment: But ... it works like that already -- at very least in EAP version. What version do you have?

Comment: I have the last version: PHPStorm 5.0.4. I am actually looking for a command so that I can see the doc inhited directly in the Sender class without having to open the interface class. I don't want to use an API doc generator either... Maybe there is a command inside PHPStorm to display the inherited doc?

Comment: It works in **EAP** build of **v6** -- you can try it yourself at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP . Command to view documentation is **View | Quick Documentation** (Ctrl+Q .. or whatever shortcut you may have there)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The upcoming **PhpStorm v6** has much better support of `{@inheritDoc}` (in comparison to **v5** and earlier).

The functionality you require is already working fine in **EAP** build (Early Access Program) -- you can try it yourself from here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP

Command to view documentation is **View | Quick Documentation** (<kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> .. or whatever shortcut you may have there)

Comment: Does the IDE not actually render the inherited doc in the class? That would be much more helpful than having to press F1 on every method.